# How to loop through content directive from a sass mixin?

Tags: css, for-loop, sass, mixins

I am trying to write a SASS mixin to dynamically loop through the number of items in an element and then apply a custom animation.

```
// MIXIN
@mixin staggerAnimation($el: $animated-elem) {
    @for $i from 1 through 4 {
        #{$el}:nth-child( #{$i} ) {
            @content
        }
    }
}

// Usage from external SASS file
$animated-elem: '.item';
@include staggerAnimation($animated-elem) {
    // This property needs to be different based on the usage
    animation: FadeIn 1s #{$el * 0.35}s ease 1 both;
}
```

Comment: What does `$el * 0.35` is supposed to do?

Comment: It's supposed to increment the animation delay. In this example, I am creating a staggered animation of elements

Comment: So, shouldn't it be `$i` instead of `$el`? Since `$el` takes the value of `$animated-elem`, which is a string (selector), there is no way you can increment anything from it. Though, with `$i` the problem still remains because you can't pass a variable from a `@mixin` to a `@content`. However, you can use a global variable, please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51479175/9718056).

Answer (score 0):

Using content block arguments (available in the latest version of Dart Sass) you could pass the `$i` value through to the `@content` block.

```
// MIXIN
@mixin staggerAnimation($el: $animated-elem) {
    @for $i from 1 through 4 {
        #{$el}:nth-child( #{$i} ) {
            @content($i)
        }
    }
}

// Usage from external SASS file
$animated-elem: '.item';
@include staggerAnimation($animated-elem) using ($i) {
    // Then you can use the $i variable however you wish in here
    animation: FadeIn 1s #{$i * 0.35}s ease 1 both;
}
```

You could even pass both variables through if needed (eg `@content($i, $el)` and `using ($i, $el)`), just make sure they are in the same order in both places.

NOTE: that this **WON'T WORK** unless you're using the latest Dart Sass compiler to compile your scss, this is a very new language feature and at time of writing it has not yet been implemented into Node Sass.